# Linqpad can open DBContext but all tables cause error

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, linqpad

I have connected to my DB in linqpad via an Entity Framework DBContext. The connection succeeds and all the tables appear in the navigation list on the left of the screen. But when I query on 'any' table I get an error of the form "Cannot execute text selection: The name 'xxxxxx' does not exist in the current context" or "The name 'xxxxx' does not exist in the current context". The log.txt gives no help. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Need some code. Also, does your log have anything at all?

Comment: To reproduce this error all I do is drag and drop one of the tables from the navigation pane into the main pane and hit F5. Log.txt records nothing

Answer (score 0):

My own problem with this was solved when I noticed that the **Connection** drop-down list was set as **<None>**. Changing that to the appropriate location of the data fixed the problem for me. The drop-down list is located to the right of the drop-down list for **Language**.

Not sure if that was your problem, since that should change automatically when you drag-and-drop a table in, and the same will happen if you right-click on the table name and select one of the options. The Fix I shared probably only works for when you type the query completely from scratch.